# Why "Winter Hats" are given not using user's local time?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, winter-bash-2013, timezone

I have received a new winter hat, which is given on vote/post on 25 December:

[image]

but in my country it is yet 24 December:

[image]

Should not be the hat given using user's local time?

Comment: Why would that be ? Everything on this site is according to SO time. Why would hats be different ?

Comment: @insertcleverxmasname It isn't UTC either, its basically if its that date anywhere in the world

Comment: And what about the astronauts checking on SO from the moon.  What's their local timezone?

Comment: @Servy The astronauts use UTC, so it's the same as the one used by SO.

Comment: @Antony They may use it just for simplicity sake, but that's not their local timezone.  I can use UTC all day long but it doesn't mean that's my *local* timezone.

Comment: Jon Skeet lives in UTC, so therefor the servers match his time.

Comment: It is so people like myself who are in timezones far ahead of you can get the hat when we earn it, rather than waiting for the sun to come up in London (figuratively speaking). I'd just like to mention that I would have been the first, or amongst the very first to earn this hat legitimately :)

Answer (score 5):

Because that would be a pain in the a** to implement.

Comment: Yeah, that can not be an answer. You want to make me believe that the programmers behind have not enough skills? Why just better say that there are more urgent things to be done.

Comment: Of course they have enough skills, but it doesn't need to be wasted on this, when they have the community to stop the onslaught of "halp why did i get tihs badge erly pls halp!"

Comment: Oh, MSO, how you make me wonder. My most well-researched answers get 1 or 2 votes, then I post an answer of exactly 11 words and get 5 votes on a question with 30 views

Comment: @scrb Yeah, Meta rep is basically meaningless. My second most upvoted post basically reads "it's a secret."